# Question about arc length of tan(ln(x))?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I tried using the arc length formula $\int_{x_a}^{x_b}\sqrt{f'(x)+1}dx$ for this function: $\tan(\ln(x))$.The result I get: $$\int\frac{\sqrt{\sec^4(\ln(x))+x^2}}{x}dx$$ (I'm just trying to find the general formula for now). I don't know how to integrate this.

Comment: Arc length between what points?

Comment: @Gary it appears to be the indefinite arc length integral without any bounds. Although perhaps a restriction of $x_a>0$  should be considered.

Comment: The inside should be $\sec^4$

Comment: Hello, please read [how to question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). One of the recommendations is to try and solve it and come up with any info you have. Also provide context for this problem. Anyways, this integral appears to be non elementary, mathematica cannot evaluate it, but we will still try to solve it.Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Here is the [new demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8pg6ge1ygz).

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, but integrating over poles of the secant is also inconvenient.

Comment: @Zuter_242   [$$\text{This may help}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133379/help-needed-with-finding-series-expansion-of-square-root-term-of-the-integrand-o)Claude Leibovici found the best answer.